# Javascript eventlistener in loop function runs too many times

Tags: javascript, function, dom, foreach, addeventlistener

I have a couple of buttons which I'm trying to loop through and add a event listener function to them. I do this by using the following code:

```
function handleButtonClick({
    target
    }) {
    const btnNode = target.closest('button');
    console.log('hi')
}
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.answerBtn');

btns.forEach(btns => {
    btns.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick)
})
```

Everytime a button is clicked it should run the function and it does. The only problem is that if I have 4 buttons, it runs the first button 4 time, the 2th button 3 times, the 3th button 2 times and the last ones. I know this happens because of the loop, but is there a way to make sure that it doesn't matter on what button I press, it only runs the function once?

```js
let clickCountStorage = new Map;

class Question {
  /**
   * @param {string} question
   * @param {string} prefix
   * @param {string} description
   * @param {string} display
   * @param {string} answerType
   * @param {string} multiSelect
   * @param {Answer[]} answers
   */
  constructor(question = "", prefix = "", description = "", display = "", answerType = "", multiSelect = "",
    answers = []) {
    this.question = question;
    this.prefix = prefix;
    this.description = description;
    this.display = display;
    this.answerType = answerType;
    this.multiSelect = multiSelect;
    this.answers = answers;
  }
}


class Answer {
  constructor(id = "", name = "") {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}

function createButton(id) {

  let generateNewAnswer = document.createElement('button');
  generateNewAnswer.setAttribute('type', 'button');
  generateNewAnswer.id = `answerBtn${ id }`;
  generateNewAnswer.classList.add('answerBtn');
  generateNewAnswer.innerHTML = 'Add Answer';

  return generateNewAnswer

}

function main() {
  function handleButtonClick() {
    let target = event.target;

    const btnNode = target.closest('button');

    const buttonClickTotal = clickCountStorage.get(btnNode) + 1;
    clickCountStorage.set(btnNode, buttonClickTotal);

    const clickCountList = Array
      .from(
        clickCountStorage.values()
      );

    const allButtonsClickTotal = clickCountList
      .reduce((total, count) => total + count, 0);

    const AllBtnsClickedThreeTimes = clickCountList
      .every(count => count >= 3);

    console.log({
      buttonClickTotal,
      allButtonsClickTotal,
      AllBtnsClickedThreeTimes,
    });
  }

  const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.answerBtn');
  console.log(btns)

  btns.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick);
    console.log(btn)
  })
}


class Structure {
  constructor() {
    /**
     * @type {Question[]}
     */
    this.questions = [];
    this.clickCount = 0;
    this.currentQuestion = this.questions.length;
    this.displayArr = ["Selecteer soort:", "button", "colorBtn", "position", "dropdown"];
    this.typeArr = ["Selecteer type:", "max", "all"];
    this.MultiArr = ["Multiselect:", "true", "false"];
  }

  AddQuestion() {
    let currentQuestion = this.questions.length;

    // The new created question which has to be added to the questions.
    let newQuestion = new Question();
    // Push the new question to the question list.
    this.questions.push(newQuestion);

    // The div generator for the answers
    let answerDIV = document.createElement('div');
    answerDIV.className = 'answerDIV' + currentQuestion;
    answerDIV.id = 'AnswerDivId' + currentQuestion;
    document.getElementsByClassName('create')[0].appendChild(answerDIV);

    let generateNewAnswer = createButton(currentQuestion);

    clickCountStorage.set(generateNewAnswer, 0)

    generateNewAnswer.onclick = _ => this.AddAnswer(currentQuestion);

    document.getElementsByClassName('create')[0].appendChild(generateNewAnswer);

  }

  /**
   * @param {int} workingQuestionIndex
   */
  AddAnswer(workingQuestionIndex) {
    let workingQuestion = this.questions[workingQuestionIndex];

    let newAnswerIndex = workingQuestion.answers.length;
    let newAnswerId = 'id' + newAnswerIndex;

    // The new answer to insert.
    let newAnswer = new Answer(newAnswerId);
    // Add the new answer to the total answers.
    workingQuestion.answers.push(newAnswer);

    let idElement = document.createElement('input');
    idElement.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    idElement.name = "id";
    idElement.id = newAnswerId;
    idElement.classList.add('id', 'QuestionNumber' + workingQuestionIndex);
    idElement.placeholder = 'Add the ID of the answer';
    idElement.addEventListener('input', function(_) {
      newAnswer.id = this.value;
    });

    // Appends the answers to the AnswerDiv
    document.getElementsByClassName('answerDIV' + workingQuestionIndex)[0].appendChild(idElement);
  }
}

class GenerateArray {

  constructor() {
    this.structure = new Structure();
  }

  generateQuestionPart() {
    this.structure.AddQuestion();
  }

}

let newQuestion = new Question();
let struc = new Structure();
NewArray = new GenerateArray();

document.querySelectorAll('.QPB')[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
  main()
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 5%);
  transform: translate(-50%, 5%);
}

.QPB {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: #ff5c01!important;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.question,
.prefix,
.description {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 95%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.SelClassD,
.SelClassT,
.SelClassM {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.SelClassD:focus,
.SelClassT:focus,
.SelClassM:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  border: 4px solid rgb(135, 206, 250, 0.5);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.question,
.description,
.prefix,
.id,
.name {
  border: 2px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.question:focus,
.description:focus,
.prefix:focus,
.id:focus,
.name:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  border: 4px solid rgb(135, 206, 250, 0.5);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.id,
.name {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 55px;
}

.answerBtn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #ff5c01!important;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.CreateArray {
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #3db556!important;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}


/* card */

.DONOT {
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.card-body-home {
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}


/* form card */

.form-card-DT {
  max-width: 800px;
  border: none!important;
  height: 100%;
  /* padding-bottom: 10px; */
}

.form-card-header {
  border: none;
  background-color: #ff5c01!important;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 0!important;
  height: 35px;
}

.form-card-body {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: solid 1px #b5b5b5;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div style='width: 1000px;margin: auto;'>
  <div class='card text-dark bg-light mb-3 form-card-DT'>
    <div class='card-header form-card-header'>Creeër een vragenlijst:</div>
    <div class='card-body form-card-body'>
      <div class="DONOT">Gebruik het volgende teken niet ivm error: '</div>
      <div class="create">
        <button id="QuestionPartBtn" class="QPB" type="button" onclick="NewArray.generateQuestionPart()">+
                    </button>
        <br><br>
      </div>
      <div class="result">
        <button id="download-btn" class="CreateArray">Generate Code</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]. My best guess is that the HTML you didn't show us is missing the end tags for the buttons, so they are nested and consequently the event is bubbling from the last one and hitting all the previous ones.

Comment: I created a smaller version of the project I'm working on on: https://codepen.io/thijsieboy007/pen/NWyjOOw?editors=1111                         I think it has something to do with the place main() is placed, But i can't figure it out

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @Quentin I see. I added a live demo inside the question itself. I'll add a better description in the code.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try to use [Event Bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling_and_capture) and assign only one "click" event listener to the closest common parent